# How to show ACF (advance custom fields) user data to gravity forms?

Tags: gravityforms

Is there anyone encountered this? I need some help. I am trying to get the value of my ACF Fields from user (current user). I want it to show in gravity forms as a (hidden field) or (merge-tag) or any other solution will work.

For example: I created a custom field using ACF name "available payout balance" then I created a form using gravity forms with (available balance field in it) it is mapping on the registration form correctly, I put 0 as default value... Now, I want to show that field (custom field) value in gravity forms.

```
{user:[meta_field_name]}
```

I tried this but it doesn't show the value the custom field of the user.

Answer (score 0):

[Gravity Forms Populate Anything](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/) supports populating pretty much any user meta into pretty much any field. Here's an example of what the field settings might look like:

[image: https://gwiz.io/2K8D26X]